# How to send a ghost email message?

Tags: linux, centos, email, internet, sip

When I was running `tcpdump` and watching output on my new created VPS (OS:CentOS 7.1) via SSH, a message appears suddenly:

```
OPTIONS sip:100@My_VPS_IP SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 69.64.57.15:5596;branch=z9hG4bK-1736040942;rport
Content-Length: 0
From: "sipvicious"<sip:100@1.1.1.1>;tag=3264346531356562313363340132313937303630383239
Accept: application/sdp
User-Agent: friendly-scanner
To: "sipvicious"<sip:100@1.1.1.1>
Contact: sip:100@69.64.57.15:5596
CSeq: 1 OPTIONS
Call-ID: 557316745284479406993575
Max-Forwards: 70
```

I firstly thought I have received a fake ip email, and confused, for I have never setup an email service.

Here comes the result of `ss -tunpl`:

```
[root@localhost ~]# ss -tunpl
Netid State      Recv-Q Send-Q                            Local Address:Port                                           Peer Address:Port              
Cannot open netlink socket: Protocol not supported
udp   UNCONN     0      0                                             *:46413                                                     *:*                   users:(("ss-server",pid=25065,fd=5))
udp   UNCONN     0      0                                            :::443                                                      :::*                   users:(("kcp_server",pid=25027,fd=3))
Cannot open netlink socket: Protocol not supported
tcp   LISTEN     0      0                                             *:22                                                        *:*                   users:(("sshd",pid=128,fd=3))
tcp   LISTEN     0      0                                     127.0.0.1:1080                                                      *:*                   users:(("ss-server",pid=25065,fd=6))
tcp   LISTEN     0      0                                            :::22                                                       :::*                   users:(("sshd",pid=128,fd=4))
[root@localhost ~]#
```

Program [ss-server](https://github.com/shadowsocks/shadowsocks-libev) and [kcp_server](https://github.com/xtaci/kcptun) are both something like a socks5 proxy server with authorization forced, which means nothing about email service has been install in my VPS(even `mail` is `Command not found`).

At the mean time, the ssh only allow RSA authorization, and I am sure my private key is safe enough. And, the `w` command shows that there is only one user online.

But, above are not important. The reason why I call this a ghost email is that both `/var/mail/` and `/var/spool/mail/` have only one empty file called rpc :

```
[root@localhost ~]# ls /var/mail       
rpc
[root@localhost ~]# file /var/mail/rpc 
/var/mail/rpc: empty
[root@localhost ~]# ls /var/spool/mail/    
rpc
[root@localhost ~]# file /var/spool/mail/rpc 
/var/spool/mail/rpc: empty
```

The email I have received disappeared!

I hope this is not a security BUG which can make my VPS unsafe.

But, the most important thing is: I want to know how it could be happened? What is the mechanism behind it?

Answer (score 2):

This is a [SIP (VoIP) probe](http://blog.sipvicious.org/), and nothing to do with SMTP or Email.